# The third link is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I created a button to take me to another page and in that other page, there is another button that takes to another page, so page1, page2 and page3 that it's not working with me, check http://oi62.tinypic.com/2m7g4et.jpg when I click on "Fish guide" it takes me to the other one which has another button "Fish", when I click on "Fish" it doesn't take me to the 3rd page!

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textStyle="italic" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fishguide"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Fish guide"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fishguide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3"
    android:textStyle="italic" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textStyle="italic" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fish"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Fish"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fish.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textStyle="italic" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/bala" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Balabanka"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.d.di;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fishguide);

        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PageThree.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

PageThree.java

```
package com.d.di;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PageThree extends Activity {

    Button button3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fishguide);
    }
}
```

I did the third page, it runs but it was .. wrong

MainActivity2.java

```
package com.d.di;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    Button fishlink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fishguide);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        fishlink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fish);

        fishlink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PageFish.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

PageFish.java

```
package com.d.di;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PageFish extends Activity {

    Button fishlink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fish);
    }
}
```

Help :)

---

Edit / it goes "Fish guide" to "Fish" when I click on "Fish" it takes me again to "Fish" and so on, it doesn't go to the third page!

PageThree.java

```
package com.d.di;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PageThree extends Activity {

    Button button3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fishguide);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fish);

        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PageThree.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't done anything on the `Button` in `PageThree` activity.

Comment: I'm a bit lost, what should I add?

Comment: You have done ` addListenerOnButton();` in `MainActivity` do the same kind of thing in `PageThree` with the `Button` that is present in its XML.

Comment: It doesn't take me to the third page, I added edit at the end of my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used

```
setContentView(R.layout.fishguide);
```

in PageThree.java

Change it to the xml you want to show with that third image in image. say, `third.xml`

```
setContentView(R.layout.third);
```

And you are done.

Comment: Do you mean setContentView(R.layout.fish); if so, it also works but it stuck! :(

Comment: Where are you stuck now? @sakhwa any crash?

Comment: Show logcat output @sakhwa

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** You are getting the same Layout again and again because in `PageThree.java` you are starting the activity with intent `PageThree.java`. Instead just change that to `PageFish.java`.

So when you are at second layout (`PageThree.java`), just start activity for third layout (`PageFish.java`) on button click as follows -

**PageThree.java**

```
package com.d.di;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PageThree extends Activity {

    Button button3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fishguide);

    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fish);

        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(PageThree.this, PageFish.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work! it game me errors on eclipse! It puts a red line under setOnClickListener says [The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})]

Comment: This is a syntax error so you look how you put your `setOnClickListener` for layout 1. The same `setOnClickListener` is for layout 2. The only difference is that you need to start activity for layout 3 inside this `onClickListener` as is shown in the answer.

Comment: You haven't saved the `PageThree.java` as I see in the image. Just save that page and if error still persists then just do Project -> Clean. The error will went away.

Comment: Unfortunately, I went to another post and it fits my code, I wish yous fits with mine!

Comment: oh ok that's fine. It looked like this fixed. Anyways happy coding!

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the code, I'll probably needs it on another thing!